# Add other parameters to saml2 authentication requets

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I try to authenticate with itfoxtec-identity-saml2 to my IDP.At first, I used asp.net webform but I need to migrate my website to asp net core mvc and i don't know how to proceed to enter theses parameters :

authentication level
Assertion consumer URL
Endpoint

And my IDP provides me a certificate to decode SAML response.

I'm very newbie with MVC.

Help would be appreciated.

Regards

I tried to use that procedure:  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp, but there's missing parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can start by cloning/downloading the git repository https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2

And then run two of the samples:

- the IdP emulator `test/TestIdPCore`
- and the ASP.NET Core MVC RP sample `test/TestWebAppCore`

Comment: I tried, to see how it works but it's not very easy to integrate it with my current project.